# JQuery append {{}} Meteor Spacebars

Tags: jquery, meteor, append

I am appending html containing SPACEBARS through following

```
var brackets = '{{' + $(this).attr('binding') + '}}';
t.$('.prodTableData').append('<td id="' + $(this).attr('id') + '">' + brackets + '</td>');
```

But in result, i get {{dynamicValue}} just like HTML. Meteor is not supposing it as a Spacebar.
What is the solution for this?

Comment: You can't really do this. Spacebars has already run, you're attempting to dynamically create a new _template_. Spacebars uses templates to create the DOM. It doesn't continuously check for `{{}}` variables and update them. You're better off bracketing this variable you're trying to insert with an `{{#if}}` in your template.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried but when `{{#if}}` gets true after removing and appending new `<td>`. it gives the previous removed `<td>` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my issue by using SPACEBAR Compiler.

https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/spacebars-compiler

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

For example:

```
var brackets = 5;
alert(brackets);
$('#panel .sidebar ul li.value').append('<td id="data-5">' + brackets + '</td>');
```

> and in your code remove brackets "{{ }}", then you can try your code

for reference you can read this document [append demo](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: thanks for the answer, but my question is also related to Meteor, i am first removing  `<td>` from DOM then appending it with a new `<td>`. Problem is Meteor is not accepting `{{value}}` as a Spacebar. It is supposing it as a simple HTML